# How to return Calendar object in Custom Date format

Tags: java, date, datetime, timestamp

How to return  calender object using this.

```
public static Calendar getDeCal(Timestamp timeStamp) {
    Calendar tempCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    tempCal.setTime(new Date(timeStamp.getTime()));
    return tempCal;
}
```

Its giving out put in this format without milliseconds.

```
2014-06-25T21:34:04+05:30
```

But  we need in this format with milliseconds

```
2014-06-25T21:34:04 .555+05:30
```

As per  above requirement i have changed the code to this format

```
public static Calendar getDateCal(Timestamp timeStamp) throws ParseException {
    Calendar tempCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat ft =  new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy.MM.dd 'T' hh:mm:ss.SS  z");
    String date1 = ft.format(timeStamp.getTime());
    tempCal.setTime(ft.parse(date1));
    return tempCal;
}
```

But its giving error while running.

Any help about this.

I am getting this error while ruining in standalone application.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.Date.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Date.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: A calendar does not (by itself) produce a String. How are you getting the output which does not contain the millisecond precision you desire?

Comment: What is your **sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo**? Because I tested your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: What is the code `at example.com.tecnotree.practice.Dateandtime.getDateandtime(Dateandtime.java:87)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the Calendar object as a variable and print it, then use the SimpleDateFormat object to format it when you are ready to display the output.
I did not see any way to automatically fill the time zone colon through the format characters so I used a substring to add one instead.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss. SSSZZZ");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

String formattedTime = sdf.format(c.getTime());

int colon = formattedTime.length()-2;
formattedTime = formattedTime.substring(0,colon) + ":"
    + formattedTime.substring(colon);

System.out.println(formattedTime);
```

Output:2015-01-05T13:30:49. 635-06:00

EDIT:
If you are looking for a single object that is a calendar and can generate output in the given format, you would have to make a new class to connect the two together. The output and the calendar object are two different things.  The calendar represent the time.  The output represents the human readable portion, the string.

```
public class PersonalCalendar extends GregorianCalendar
{
  SimpleDateFormat sdf;
  public PersonalCalendar(Timestamp timestamp)
  {
    super();
    setTime(timestamp);
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss. SSSZZZ");
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    String formattedTime = sdf.format(getTime());
    int colon = formattedTime.length()-2;
    formattedTime = formattedTime.substring(0,colon) + ":"+ formattedTime.substring(colon);
    return formattedTime;
  }
}
```

In use.

```
Calendar c = new PersonalCalendar(timestamp);
System.out.println(c.toString());
```

Output:2015-01-06T09:29:29. 783-06:00

Comment: Its returning string not the calendar type ..please check i wnat return calender itself.I have parse also its giving parsing error..

Comment: You need to clarify what you want.  Are you looking for a formatted string for a Calendar?  Do you want help on how to set the time on a Calendar object?  Do you want help with IllegalArgumentException? It's confusing because it looks like you are trying ask three questions at once.

Comment: I just want above date format and return to the method with calendar type

Comment: Therefore, I think using the PersonalCalendar example in the answer is your best bet to have  a single object.  The existing Java classes do not do what you want in a single class.  The only other option I could see is to modify the code where you produce your output.  It may help to know more about the code producing your output.